# Swift CLI: run process, display its output and allow user input

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, nstask

I've been trying for some days now to find and equivalent to Ruby's `exec` in Swift.

I haven't yet been able to find a solution. Multiple sources online suggest how to forward predefined input to STDIN of the child process and out to read its output, but now how to start a child process and let it take control of the STDIN and STDOUT as if the Swift process was letting it take over.

The use case would be to run SSH commands and develop an in-house company tool, formerly in Ruby, that would allow similar features as `heroku run /bin/sh` for instance. I am already able to replicate things like `heroku logs`, since they donnot require user input.

The basic idea of starting a new process and attaching it to STDIN and STDOUT doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["bash", "-c", "read"]
task.standardInput = FileHandle.standardInput
task.standardOutput = FileHandle.standardOutput
task.standardError = FileHandle.standardError
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Any ideas or hints of how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Apple's Foundation. The intended behaviour should be that not assigning any of those would get you your desired result. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1411576-standardinput) says:

> If this method isn’t used, the standard input is inherited from the process that created the receiver.

(Similar things are said for `stdout` and `stderr` too)

However, `stdin` doesn't seem to be actually connected, so your input is being received by your Swift process, rather than `bash -c read`.

According to this similar discussion [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-allow-process-to-receive-user-input-when-run-as-part-of-an-executable-e-g-to-enabled-sudo-commands/34357/1) on Swift Forums about allowing users to enter passwords into a subprocess,

- `Process` is a wrapper around `posix_spawn`, but calling `posix_spawn` directly works
- Rust's `Command` and Python's `subprocess.run` also use `posix_spawn`, but they work correctly.
- Building the [`SwiftFoundation`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) framework from source and using the `Process` class from *that*, also works.

Based on the above points, I think this is a bug.

For now, you can use this workaround (this is also from the Swift Forums post)

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", "read"]
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardInput = pipe
let fileHandle = FileHandle(fileDescriptor: STDIN_FILENO)
fileHandle.readabilityHandler = { handle in
    let data = handle.availableData
    if data.count > 0 {
       pipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
    }
}
try task.run()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: That is a beautiful answer, thank you so much! I was able to test it with ssh (adding the `-tt` option so it doesn't require a PTY on STDIN) and it seems to work very nicely!

Comment: After some more testing, launching a task for `/usr/bin/env` with arguments `ssh -tt root@host irb`, assuming host doesn't require a password and `irb` is installed on it, leaves you with ANSI escape codes roaming around and lines starting with something like `▽^[[32;2R`. Would you have any suggestion on how to handle this properly ? If i find anything on my end I'll be sure to report back here!